# Make a exported function ansi and unicode aware in win32 dll with the use of TCHAR

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I'm trying to make a win32 dll that are able to handle ansi and unicode depending what specify in the character set on properties. Unicode or Not Set. ANSI when building in Visual Studio.

The dll has the definition

```
extern "C" int __stdcall calc(TCHAR *foo)
```

The definition file is as follow

```
typedef int (CALLBACK* LPFNDLLCALC)( TCHAR *foo)
```

Inside the MFC Calling app i load the dll as this

```
HINSTANCE DllFoo = LoadLibrary(L"foo.dll");
LPFNDLLCALC lpfnDllcalc = (LPFNDLLCALC)GetProcAddress(DllFoo ,"calc");

CString C_SerialNumber;
mvSerialNumber.GetWindowText(C_SerialNumber);
TCHAR* SerialNumber = C_SerialNumber.GetBuffer(0);

LPFNDLLCALC(SerialNumber);
```

I understand that i make something wrong in the C_SerialNumber.GetBuffer(0) to the TCHAR* pointer. Because in the debugger in the dll only show the first char is passed to the dll. Not the complete string.

How do i get CString to pointer that work in both ansi and unicode.

If change all my code to wchar_t or char in stead of TCHAR i get it to work. Put not with this nativ TCHAR macro.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be better to use `wchar_t`? Use `TCHAR` when you need to compile for Win 98.

Comment: I need to work with VBA Excel and also Unicode C#, another way is duplicate all code to a foo_a(char* foo) and foo_w(wchar_t* foo ) but not want that road. To bad C++/C programmer to get it to work with TCHAR way. And i don't understand why.

Comment: The way Windows API does that is by having a DLL export two functions, say `calcA` and `calcW`, then defining a macro `calc` that expands to one or the other. Try using `GetProcAddress` to obtain a pointer to, say, `CreateWindow` - no such symbol is exported from `user32.dll`. Instead, `CreateWindowA` and `CreateWindowW` are exported. The caller has to decide which flavor they want to call.

Comment: Your approach is only going to work if both the DLL and its client are compiled with the same ANSI vs Unicode setting. You see the problem because they are compiled with different settings: in the calling application, `SerialNumber` is `wchar_t*`. You then effectively do `reinterpret_cast<char*>` on it when calling the ANSI flavor of `calc`. Unicode strings tend to have every other byte as zero; when interpreted as an ANSI string, it looks like one character followed by NUL terminator.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Well, it could work if the caller told the library whether or not the text was narrow or wide, and then the library could choose the appropriate path with appropriate conversions. But that way lies madness.

Comment: @JohanBertilsdotter In case you still don't understand, what a `TCHAR` is is decided at compile time by the preprocessor. Your DLL supports both Ansi and Unicode depending on how it was compiled - it can't support them both at the same time.

Comment: @David Heffernan `it could work if the caller told the library whether or not the text was narrow or wide` Quite. And one way to do this is to provide two entry points, one accepting narrow strings and the other wide. Then the caller would "tell the library" by way of calling the appropriate entry point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David said, you need to export two separate functions, one for Ansi and one for Unicode, just like the Win32 API does, eg:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int WINAPI calcA(LPCSTR foo);
int WINAPI calcW(LPCWSTR foo);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

typedef int (WINAPI *LPFNDLLCALC)(LPCTSTR foo);
```

Then you can do the following:

```
int WINAPI calcA(LPCSTR foo)
{
    return calcW(CStringW(foo));
}

int WINAPI calcW(LPCWSTR foo)
{
    //...
}
```

```
HINSTANCE DllFoo = LoadLibrary(L"foo.dll");
LPFNDLLCALC lpfnDllcalc = (LPFNDLLCALC) GetProcAddress(DllFoo,
    #ifdef UNICODE
    "calcW"
    #else
    "calcA"
    #endif
);

CString C_SerialNumber;
mvSerialNumber.GetWindowText(C_SerialNumber);
lpfnDllcalc(C_SerialNumber);
```

Comment: After reading this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc this is best answer. Tanks.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't implement it this way. I'd use macros to select W or A versions. And load time linking. So, just as it's done in Win32.

Answer (score 2):

As I see it you have two options:

1. Write the code entirely using `TCHAR`. Then compile the code into two separate DLLs, one narrow and one wide.
2. Have a single DLL that exports two variants of each function that operates on text. This is how the Windows API is implemented.

If you choose the second option, you don't need to implement each function twice. The primary function is the wide variant. For the narrow variant you convert the input from narrow to wide and then call the wide version. Vice versa for output text. In other words, you use the adapter pattern.

I suppose that you are imagining a third option where you have a single function that can operate on either form of text. Don't go this way. This way abandons type safety and will give you no end of pain. It will also be counter to user's expectations.